# How to make this Header/Content/Footer/Menu layout using CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, header

I have been trying all day to create this kind of website template in CSS without succeeding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. THX

- The header should be always visible even if we scroll
- The menu's height is the size of Header + Content + footer
- Content can be scrolled and size can be higher than the browser window
- Footer should be displayed after the content

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

+  M +                                  HEADER                                                 +
+  E  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  N  +
+      +                                CONTENT                                                +
+  U  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+      +                                 FOOTER                                                 +,
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[Layout](http://s18.postimg.org/p6lg4y52h/Untitled.png)

Comment: Have you considered using one of the many predefined CSS templates that are out there on the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="left-bar">
        <div class="menu">
            MENU
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar">
        <div class="header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    * {text-align:center;}
    html, body {margin:0; padding:0;}
    .page {position:relative;}
    .left-bar {position:absolute; left:0px; width:200px; height:100%; border-right:2px solid red;}
    .right-bar {margin-left:200px; padding-top:150px;}
    .header {position:fixed; left:200px; top:0px; right:0px; height:150px; border:2px solid blue; background:#eeeeee;}
    .content {height:1000px;} /*replace with height:auto; for real content*/
    .footer {height:40px; border-top:2px solid green; background:#eeeeee;}
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using Bootstrap. http://examples.getbootstrap.com/

You can easily create a sticky left menu that will also be responsive for devices of all sizes.

Comment: That's not really answering the question. The OP has given specific requirements and there's no mention of how to do it with Bootstrap. Incidentally there is no Bootstrap example that covers these exact requirements.